# Has anyone had issues with march update regarding metadata service?

Tags: managed-metadata-service, update

Since the update I've noticed that the managed metadata service is not working correctly anymore. The Term Store can be accessed via central admin, but not from site settings.

I've reset IIS, and set read permissions for the app pool service account (althought this was not set before, no issues had occurred). Still have not been able to access term store.

Update:

> Error encountered in background cache check System.Security.SecurityException:     Requested registry access is not allowed.

Comment: did you check the ULS logs or event log for more details? what error u getting? one more thing, if you un associated the MMS proxy from the web app and then re associate it. then test again

Comment: Do you mean remove the proxy then recreate it?

Comment: I mean from Web app service connection...remove mms click ok....after that wait a min and again add it

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it did not resolve it. Also tried recreating an entirely new MMS and it did not work either.

Comment: check this one. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/edf7946a-a178-46e8-b7f3-82f80ad4a194/have-anyone-set-up-mysite-on-a-frontend-server-and-userporfile-service-application-on-an-appserver?forum=sharepointadmin you have to run the psconfig command line

Comment: This worked, although it appears that I have lost all of the site specific terms.

Comment: so this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, will you make a comment so I can mark the answer please? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **SPResourceSecurity** not properly registered.

open cmd as administrator

type:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN
```

then type:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/edf7946a-a178-46e8-b7f3-82f80ad4a194/have-anyone-set-up-mysite-on-a-frontend-server-and-userporfile-service-application-on-an-appserver?forum=sharepointadmin